# Javascript to modify text in dynamically loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage that is hosted in the cloud (so I don't have access to the source code), but I'm allowed to "inject" JS at the bottom of the page.
There is a button that, when pressed, will do the following:

1. Use ajax to retrieve data
2. Create a new HTML  with the contents retrieved
3. Uses jQuery to fadeOut the original button and fadeIn the new  contents

I need to modify text in the new  that gets created. 
The button looks like:

```
<button class="subform add" onclick="addSubform(stuff); return false;" ...></button>
```

The div that is created looks like:

```
<div class=" section subform container" id="myId" style=""><div class="subformheader"><h4>Text I want to modify</h4>
```

Since I can't access the source code, I can't change the fadeIn to include a callback to modify the text.

I tried to tie into the events for the button's click using addEventListener():

```
let buttonNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('section subform container')
buttonNodes[0].addEventListener('change', function(){alert("clicked me!")});
```

But b/c the "addsubForm()" function is ajax, my function gets executed before the ajax call gets the results and creates the new .

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: I’d be interested to know/learn why the downvotes so I could improve whatever they felt was deficient/missing or poorly written?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should read [ask] to see what's expected of a good question. Your question shows no attempt to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the response.  I thought my last line about having tried the addEventListener() was communicating what I tried, but perhaps I should have given more details?  I thought that would have cluttered the question b/c the result was that my function executed before the ajax call finished, so I just included that "result" instead of the function itself.  But maybe that's bad form.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mutation observer. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

The problem with Mutation observers is that they're very finicky to setup. For instance, even though it's the same exact code, the code below works better in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b9sdLzrv/15/ - though I suspect that might be due to the environment.

Basically what you want to do is to test when an elements node has changed using a mutation observer. The observer allows for a callback, and then provides a method (`observe`) to attach it to a target element with allowed options.

That all being said, your situation is precarious. It would be best to reach out to whomever can edit the code and have them do it, or to simply find an alternative method. Not being able to touch code and/or altering it from a script after DOM load despite the initial setup is in very poor taste as it can lead to many issues in the future.

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'Original Change Text');
}).then(msg => {
  document.querySelector("#myId").innerHTML = `<h4>${msg}</h4>`;
});



let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation) {
  document.querySelector("#myId").innerHTML = `<h4>immediately change the text on change`;
observer.disconnect();
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector("#myId"), {
  childList: true
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class=" section subform container" id="myId" style="">
    <div class="subformheader">
      <h4>Text I want to modify</h4>
    </div>
```

Comment: I’ll look at this tomorrow, thank you for your reply. I agree about the precariousness, the source code is controlled by a vendor so we really can’t modify or request anything. It’s definitely a hack, I agree, but they’ve actually said that if we need to customize the pages, to do it by injecting JS after the DOM loads like this. So... here I am :) Not my design

Comment: @mppowe They're probably talking about using simple JS to add to the static elements, they didn't anticipate that you'd want to customize the dynamic elements, or they would have provided hooks for that.

Comment: Thanks, got Mutation Observers to work, appreciate it!